# composition of homemomerphism and continuous function and limit at $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $h\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}h(x)=0$  and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}h(x)=0.$ Let $f\colon (a,b)\to\Bbb R$ be a homeomoerphism. I do not see why $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^{+}}(h\circ f)(x)=0 \ \  \text{and} \ \  \lim_{x\rightarrow b^{-}}(h\circ f)(x)=0.$$   Does that correct? What does this tell me in terms of cluster point of $h\circ g$, that is, it says $0$ is cluster point of $h\circ f$ at $a$ and $b$ ? Is that right? Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Let f:(a,b)→R be a homeomoerphism."

Comment: @QthePlatypus, homeomoerphism in the topological sense means $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous and $f$ is bijection .

Comment: In the question $a$ and $b$ seem to be being used as constants.  So $f(a,b)$ would be a point, however  homeomoerphism is a property of a function.

Comment: Also your limit seems to be calling $f$ with only one argument.

Comment: @QthePlatypus, Of course, $a$  and $b$ are just numbers.

Comment: @QthePlatypus not sure what your points you're trying to make. OP's notation is completely standard and the question is understandable. One thing I would correct is the inclusion sign in $h\in \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where it should be a colon.

Comment: @CSquared, I fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a homeomorphism.

**Claim:** We claim that $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}f(x)=\infty$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}f(x)=-\infty$.

**Proof:** Suppose $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}f(x)\neq\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}f(x)\neq-\infty$.

Then, there exists an $M>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists an $x\in (a,b)$ with $0<b-x<\delta$ but $f(x)\leq M$ (this is the direct negation of $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}f(x)=\infty$).

Similarly, there exists an $m>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists an $x\in(a,b)$ with $0<b-x<\delta$ but $-m\leq f(x)$.

Since $f$ is continuous and injective on $(a,b)$ into $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Suppose first that it is strictly increasing.

Suppose, for contradiction, there exists a $y\in(a,b)$ with $f(y)>M$. Then $b-y>0$ so there exists an $x\in(a,b)$ with $b-x<b-y$ and $f(x)\leq M<f(y)$ but $y<x$, contradicting the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing.

This means we must have $f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. But then $M$ is an upper bound for the image of $f$, which is equal to $\mathbb{R}$, and is thus a contradiction, since $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded. The case when $f$ is strictly decreasing is similar. This completes the proof of the claim.

Since $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function with $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}h(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}f(x)=\pm\infty$, then we must have that $$\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}(h\circ f)(x)=0\tag{$\star$}$$

If anything is unclear, I would be happy to elaborate.

Edit: We want to show that $0$ is a cluster point of $h\circ f$.

Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $0$ and let $r>0$. Since $U$ is an open neighborhood of $0$, there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$. Set $B=(b-r,b+r)$. We want to show that $(h\circ f)^{-1}(U)\cap B\neq\emptyset$. By $(\star)$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<b-x<\delta$, then $|(h\circ f)(x)|<\varepsilon$. We can modify $\delta$ to be arbitrarily small if needed so that $b-r<b-\delta<x<b$. Then, for $x\in(a,b)$ with $0<b-x<\delta$, we have $|(h\circ f)(x)|<\varepsilon$, which implies $x\in (h\circ f)^{-1}(U)$, and we also have $x\in(b-r,b+r)$.

Comment: C. Squared. Thank for your answer . you said $b-y>0$ so there exists $x\in(a,b)$ with $f(x)\leq M$ why such $x$ exists? Also, can we say now 0 is cluster point of $ h\circ g$ at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @00GB I took $b-y=\delta$ in the direct negation of $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}f(x)=\infty$. Yes, you can say that $0$ is a cluster point of $h\circ f$ near $a$ and $b$.

Comment: C Squared. I was wondering if there is a weak condition for $h$ rather than the continuity to make this still holds

Comment: @00GB The only condition on $h$ that you need for this to hold is $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}h(x)=0$. One example: $h(x)=1/x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $h(x)=0$ for $x=0$.

Comment: C Squared. You are right I  was thinking about something else. Thank you

Comment: C Squared. One part still unclear for me . how you say 0 is cluster point at the end point by using the definition

Comment: @00GB what is your definition?

Comment: C Squared. $y$ is cluster point of function $f$ at $x$ if for any open set $U$ with $y\in U $ for any $r>0$ we have $ f^{-1} (U)\cap (x-r,x+r)\neq\emptyset$ . This is only a definition that I know

Comment: @00GB will edit my answer to show this

Comment: @00GB Does it look good now?

Comment: C Squared, This looks perfect.Thank you very much

Comment: C Squared., I do have one more question that is related to that. Can we discuss in the chat if you have time

Comment: @00GB Yes thats fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123801/discussion-between-00gb-and-c-squared).